# Unable to connect to the test node by using External Http Provider in Remix

Tags: blockchain, remix, go-ethereum

I am setting up a private Ethereum chain, and the node is deployed on a Google Cloud server. I have successfully connected it to Metamask.

I can choose the "Injected Provider - Metamask" environment in Remix to connect to the node.
However, when I select "External Http Provider," I am unable to connect to the node.

This is the code I used to start a test node:

```
geth --datadir dev-chain --dev --http --http.api web3,eth,net --http.corsdomain https://remix.ethereum.org --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545
```

When I input `http://<ip_address>:8545` in the "External HTTP Provider Endpoint", I receive the following response:

```
"Error while connecting to the provider, provider not connected."
```

How can I use the External HTTP Provider to connect to a node on a cloud server?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Remix, when using HTTPS communication, only accepts URIs that begin with "https://".

To address this limitation, I registered a domain, obtained a certificate, and set up an Nginx proxy to forward traffic to port 8545. This allowed Remix to connect successfully.